# Get the nth occurrence of a letter in a string (python)

Tags: python-3.x, string, find

Let's say there is a string `"abcd#abcd#a#"`

How to get the index of the 2nd occurrence of '#' , and get the output as 9?
Since the position of the second occurrence of '#' is 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generator expression:

```
text = "abcd#abcd#a#"
gen = (i for i, l in enumerate(text) if l == "#")

next(gen) # skip as many as you need
4

next(gen) # get result
9
```

As a function:

```
def index_for_occurrence(text, token, occurrence):
    gen = (i for i, l in enumerate(text) if l == token)
    for _ in range(occurrence - 1):
        next(gen)
    return next(gen)
```

Result:

```
index_for_occurrence(text, "#", 2)
9
```

Comment: Nice,
Also, in the generator code, we can use:
`n=input(); for i in range(0,n-1): next(gen); 
 
 print(next(gen))`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'abcd#abcd#a#'
s.index('#', s.index('#')+1)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.