# Pythonic way to replace a character from a specific position in a string

Tags: python, string, indexing, replace

Consider the word "Data Analytycs" for example.
I would like to write a code which specifies "Replace second y of the string". Could someone please explain the most pythonic way to do this?

I kind of wrote the below mentioned code by simply using the index of the charater to be changed. But the case here is what if i don't know the exact index and i simply wanted to change some "nth" (like first, second, third,etc.,) repeated character of the string with another character without knowing the actual index. like here i want to replace second "y" with "i" but the actual position is 11. Thanks.

```
a="data analytycs"
list_of_original= list(a) 
print (list(a))
for i in list_of_original:
    list_of_a[11]='i'
    print ("".join(list_of_a))
    break
```

Comment: You need to replace `11` by some code which determines the index of the second 'y'.

Comment: The `for` loop is totally unnecessary because you don't use `i` and use `break` unconditionally after the first iteration.

Comment: @Elerium115 what is `locate`?

Comment: You need to import it from more_itertools library

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430123/get-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-letter-in-a-string-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228299/changing-a-character-in-a-string